# Submenu immediately disappears

Tags: css

I am creating a submenu which shows on hover of the parent menu. But when I try to go to submenu after hoving on the parent, it immediately disappears. I know there should not be any gap between parent and child menu to make the navigation seamless, but not able to figure out in the below code. I know this could be a trivial issue, any help would be appreciated.

```css
        body {
            margin: 0;
            
        }
        a {
            color:white;
            width:55px;
        }
        header {
            background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
        }
        ul {
            list-style: none;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0
        }
        ul.parent {
            display: flex;
            list-style: none;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0
        }
        a {
            display: block;
            text-decoration: none;
            padding: 10px 30px;
            margin: 0 60px;
            background-color: black
        }
        .child {
            display: none;
            position: absolute;
            top: 38px;
            left: 30px;
        }
        a:hover ~ .child {
            display: block;
            
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
   
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <ul class="parent">
            <li >
                <a class="test" href="#">Home<i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>
                <div class="child">
                    <ul >
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Item1</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Item2</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Item3</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">About</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Contact</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </header>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a class to the list with submenu and add hover to that class

```css
        body {
            margin: 0;
            
        }
        a {
            color:white;
            width:55px;
        }
        header {
            background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
        }
        ul {
            list-style: none;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0
        }
        ul.parent {
            display: flex;
            list-style: none;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0
        }
        a {
            display: block;
            text-decoration: none;
            padding: 10px 30px;
            background-color: black
        }
        .parent li{
           margin-left:60px;
         }
        .child {
            display: none;
            position: absolute;
            top: 38px;
            left: 30px;
        }
        .hasSub:hover .child {
            display: block;
            
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
   
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <ul class="parent">
            <li class="hasSub">
                <a class="test" href="#">Home<i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>
                <div class="child">
                    <ul >
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Item1</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Item2</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Item3</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">About</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Contact</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </header>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it works , but i would need the submenu to appear  only when hovered over "a" tag but currently it appears even outside the anchor tag content area(the dark black area).

Comment: I updated my answer, you need to remove margin from `a` tag and give it to `li` tag.

Comment: Thanks Aditya, It works. Just for my understanding, why hover on `a` tag doesn't work but `li` tag works ?

Comment: @lavender, Hover on `a` doesn't work because the ul is not part of the `a` tag, it is part of `li` tag, so when you hover on the second `ul` you are still in the parent `li` element.

Answer (score 1):

Just change the code:

```
a:hover ~ .child {
  display: block;
}
```

to:

```
li:hover .child {
  display: block;
}
```

**Suggestion:**

Please update your code like this, otherwise, if you trying to add another child for a menu it will not work.

```
.child {
            display: none;
            position: absolute;
            top: 100%;
            left: 30px;
        }
        ul.parent li {
          position: relative;
        }
        ul.parent li:hover .child {
            display: block;            
        }
```

I hope you understood the thing.

Check this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/15h6jyg4/

Comment: this is not work, need ul:hover instead of li:hover

Comment: @Ali, it works , but i would need the submenu to appear only when hovered over "a" tag but currently it appears even outside the anchor tag content area(the dark black area)

Comment: @lavender If you add display block for the `.child` when hovering of `a` tag, it will work, but when you leave the `a` tag it will not show the div. So you can use jQuery for this, or you can update the code like this: https://jsfiddle.net/h07vway8/